# Text area validation in IE 8 not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer

I've textarea which is working fine in all browser expect IE 8.

```
document.getElementById('verb').onkeypress = function validate(e) {

  if (String.fromCharCode((window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,\s]/) == null) {
    alert('Part Number answers must be entered in alphanumeric characters only. \n\nIf you are going to enter more than one Part Number, \nplease use a " , " comma and no space.');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

So its a normal textarea with id of verb and In that I only want space, ',' and alphanum.
It's not working in IE 8 don't know why can any one please help.

Answer (score 0):

Your feature detection fails, since `e` is `undefined` in IE8. Try something like this:

```
.onkeypress = function validate(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if ((String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode)).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,\s]/) === null) {
        alert(...);
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
           evt.preventDefault();
        }
        evt.cancelBubble = true;
        evt.returnValue = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the error I can see in IE8 console.  'which' is null or not an object

Comment: In that case you've different code than in the answer.

Comment: No I've tried in a totally new clean file having only this script and textarea

Comment: error: Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: @RIK There was some parenthesis missing in my code, fixed, tested and works.

Comment: I fixed that but I am getting Object doesn't support this property or method line 14 which is

Comment: if (String.fromCharCode((evt.which || evt.keyCode).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,\s]/) == null)) {

Comment: @RIK Notice that everything before `.match` is also wrapped in parenthesis: `if ((String.fromCharCode(evt.which || evt.keyCode)).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,\s]/) === null)`

Answer (score 0):

instead use this

```
document.getElementById('verb').onkeypress = function(e) {
 if (String.fromCharCode((window.event) ? e.which : e.keyCode).match(/[A-Za-z0-9,\s]/) == null) {
    alert('Part Number answers must be entered in alphanumeric characters only. \n\nIf you are going to enter more than one Part Number, \nplease use a " , " comma and no space.');
    e.preventDefault();
  }
};
```

Never pass the event as a named function (I don't thing that will work in IE8 ,just remove "validate"), also you can use a jQuery event to make everything shorter:

@RIK : here is working, some cleanup and is ok now:

```
$(function(){
    $("#myfield").on("keydown",function(e){
        var keyPressEvent = String.fromCharCode(e.keyCode);
        if (keyPressEvent.match(/[A-Za-z0-9,\s]/) == null) {
            alert('Part Number answers must be entered in alphanumeric characters only. \n\n'
                  +'If you are going to enter more than one Part Number, \n'
                  +'please use a " , " comma and no space.');
            e.preventDefault();
          }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/JH2kp/

other thing you may considerate, is that now a days, the rate of people using IE8 is very low. As jan 2014 the market share of IE8 is just 3.8% from a total of share of 10.2%, so I just think you should upgrade your browser or let know your customers to upgrade to IE9 or 10 that is more compatible than IE8. w3schools.com/browsers/browsers_explorer.asp

Comment: this is the error I can see in IE8 console.  'which' is null or not an object

Comment: Instead of posting second answer. Try to update existing answer.

Comment: @SpiderCode : thanks, I just updated everything in one answer.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent entering characters not in your whitelist in IE, listen to the keydown event.

(The other browsers also return a keyCode onkeydown.)

You also need to set the returnValue to false, IE8 doesn't do preventDefault.

```
function validate(e){
    e= e || window.event;
    var k= e.keyCode || '';
    if(/![A-Za-z0-9,\s]/.test(String.fromCharCode(k)){
        alert('Part Number blah...');
        if(e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();
        else e.returnValue= false;
        return false;
    }
};
document.getElementById('verb').onkeydown= validate;
```

Comment: actually it's not returning any error but I can input illegal chars.

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me. Don't why all the above didn't work

```
    document.getElementById('verb').onkeypress = function validate(e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    if(evt.which== 'undefined') console.log('which');else{console.log(evt.which)}
    if(evt.keyCode.match== 'undefined') console.log('key');else{console.log(evt.keyCode);}
     var code = evt.keyCode;
     console.log(code);
    if (/[A-Za-z0-9,\s]/.test(String.fromCharCode(code))) {
     console.log('inside');
    }else{
     alert('dddd');
        evt.returnValue = false;    
    }
}
```